# API for Android or iOS connecting to EV3 by bluetooth

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, programming

There is official API for Windows, WindowsPhone8 and WinRT https://legoev3.codeplex.com/ it lets you connect to EV3 brick and control it remotely from your WindowsPhone.

Are there any libraries available for Android (Java) or iOS (Objective-C)?

I would like to write custom app for myself that will let me steer my own robots (using either Android or iOS device).

Comment: Hmm, I imagine there will be eventually - I'm guessing MS offered to release the Windows one as LEGO hadn't released the "Commander" app on their platform. LEGO did release a BlueTooth Developer Kit and Mobile Application Software for the NXT so it's probably coming.

Comment: Taking a look at the code in the Windows API, there are no external dependencies - so assuming you have access to the Bluetooth ports on iOS/Andriod, there should be nothing stopping you porting this to your platform of choice with a little effort - the main "API" is in the [Lego.Ev3.Core](https://legoev3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Lego.Ev3.Core) namespace, which is pulled into the Phone/Desktop/WinRT projects that provide the communication wrappers that are then used by the sample projects - the Desktop project has the added excitement of Brian's WIImote support ;)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid how about Xamarin would it work on iOS

Answer (score 3):

I have started a c++ iOS API at https://github.com/dsjove/legoev3cpp. Contributions are welcome.

Comment: Are you still working on this?  How far did you get?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an android app to do exactly this using [LEJOS](http://www.lejos.org/).
I have an example java project that uses bluetooth communication [here](https://github.com/PeterMitrano/EV3-Grid-Navigation)
I'll come back with a link to the actual android app project later, but this will get you started.

Comment: Did you ever do the android app as I need a way to read sensors and controls motors from android to multiple ev3

Comment: I did, although you'll have to devise a protocol for controlling stuff since I just used raw socket IO. I'll get a link to the android project if I still have it

Comment: Thank you, any help would be awesome, I really want to communicate between multiple EV3 and a Android tablet but 1 step at a time :)

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/PeterMitrano/EV3-Android-Controller) the project on my github. Hope it helps!

Comment: I think your upload failed man, no src there!

Comment: link is fixed now

Comment: Did you ever work out how to read sensors, if you could work that out WOW, so useful to people!

Comment: This was a school project from a while ago, and I don't even own the robot anymore. So,  no I didn't do that, but you should be able to figure it out given my sample

Answer (score 2):

There's an official app released by LEGO called the LEGO MINDSTORMS COMMANDER.  It's available on both [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.mindstorms.robotcommander&hl=en) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lego-mindstorms-robot-commander/id681786521?mt=8).

I believe this is what you are looking for.  LMC lets you control the EV3 brick via bluetooth on your smartphone.  It's not exactly an API, but it lets you control the EV3.