# Bluetooth connection to EV3 from Java on Linux/Android

Tags: ev3, programming, bluetooth, lejos

I would like to connect to my EV3 from PC (and then Android) via Bluetooth.
I was able to connect to NXT with [LEGO-MINDSTORMS-MINDdroid](https://github.com/NXT/LEGO-MINDSTORMS-MINDdroid) which uses direct LCP commands but as far as I know the communication language for EV3 is different from that of NXT.

I have installed [lejos](http://www.lejos.org/) 0.9.1-beta on my EV3 and I could communicate with it via USB and WiFi using lejos' HelloWorld example containing `BrickFinder.getDefault()` for connecting.

I have followed [Abid's tutorial](https://abidmujtaba.blogspot.hu/2014/04/connecting-to-ev3-running-lejos-using.html?showComment=1481277416599#c5803985418525394242) for connecting from Linux. It did not work with Ubuntu 16.04 but it did with Ubuntu 14.04. I could ssh to the brick (I guess because 16.04 uses Bluez 5 while 14.04 and lejos uses Bluez 4). Bluez 4 and 5 seems [incompatible](http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-0/).). However `BrickFinder.getDefault()` still does not find the brick. (It is not clear whether this function checks Bluetooth at all.)

What should I do to create a Bluetooth connection from Linux (preferably Ubuntu 16.04) and Android?

I would like to avoid low-level bluetooth programming/direct commands as I have no experience with it and I prefer a java solution. Lejos on the brick's side is not a priority.

Comment: Does this help? http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/5930/3498

Comment: @David Lechner I have seen this page but there was no mention of Bluetooth in the source of Peter Mitrano's project. I will check it more thoroughly.

Comment: The BrickFinder source code is at https://sourceforge.net/p/lejos/ev3/code/ci/master/tree/ev3classes/src/lejos/hardware/BrickFinder.java. It seems the .getDefault() method iterates over all interfaces returned by the Java call NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(). Once bnep0 is created I would think it would be listed here and the EV3 should consequently become discoverable. Would need to hack this code to test what the problem is.

Comment: I have found out that socket.receive in BrickFinder.find throws a SocketTimeoutException even if I raise setSoTimeout to MAX_DISCOVERY_TIME from MAX_DISCOVERY_TIME/4. Ping to EV3 from Ubuntu is working. Bluetooth communication from Android to EV3 is also working.